# ClassCastException in sonarqube custom java check

Tags: java, sonarqube, classloader, classcastexception

Hi I'm writing own plugin for sonarqube version 6.1 using checks from java-plugin in version 4.0. To be more specific I'm trying to extend class SubscriptionVisitor to get help in Java file crawling. But I encountered this problem:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.sonar.java.model.declaration.MethodTreeImpl cannot be cast to org.sonar.java.model.JavaTree
at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:116)
at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:97)
at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.scanTree(SubscriptionVisitor.java:78)
at main.java.visitors.VariableVisitor.scan(VariableVisitor.java:50)
at main.java.disharmonies.BrainMethod.visitMethod(BrainMethod.java:51)
at org.sonar.java.model.declaration.MethodTreeImpl.accept(MethodTreeImpl.java:218)
at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:37)
at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitClass(BaseTreeVisitor.java:69)
at org.sonar.java.model.declaration.ClassTreeImpl.accept(ClassTreeImpl.java:198)
at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:37)
at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitCompilationUnit(BaseTreeVisitor.java:55)
at org.sonar.java.model.JavaTree$CompilationUnitTreeImpl.accept(JavaTree.java:156)
at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
at main.java.disharmonies.BrainMethod.scanFile(BrainMethod.java:29)
at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.visitFile(VisitorsBridge.java:123)
at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:84)
```

MethodTreeImpl clearly extends the JavaTree class. I assume the problem will be in different classloader.
Can anybody help me please?

Edit

Here is the plugin's pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <name>Disharmonies checker</name>
    <groupId>tlestyan.thesis</groupId>
    <artifactId>disharmonies</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
  <packaging>sonar-plugin</packaging>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <sonar.buildVersion>6.1</sonar.buildVersion>
    <sonar-java.version>4.0</sonar-java.version>
    <jdk.min.version>1.8</jdk.min.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.sonarsource.sonarqube</groupId>
      <artifactId>sonar-plugin-api</artifactId>
      <version>${sonar.buildVersion}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-checks</artifactId>
        <version>${sonar-java.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-java-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${sonar-java.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.sslr-squid-bridge</groupId>
            <artifactId>sslr-squid-bridge</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar.sslr</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sslr-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sonar-plugin-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar.sslr</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sslr-xpath</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.sonarsource.sonarqube</groupId>
      <artifactId>sonar-testing-harness</artifactId>
      <version>${sonar.buildVersion}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.5</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-checks-testkit</artifactId>
            <version>${sonar-java.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.sslr</groupId>
            <artifactId>sslr-testing-harness</artifactId>
            <version>1.21</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.sonar-packaging-maven-plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-packaging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.17</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
          <configuration>
                    <pluginKey>sonarMetricProject</pluginKey>
                    <pluginClass>main.java.plugin.Plugin</pluginClass>
                    <pluginName>SonarQube Disharmonies Plugin</pluginName>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                    <pluginDescription> Collects disharmonies metrics </pluginDescription>
                </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>${jdk.min.version}</source>
          <target>${jdk.min.version}</target>

        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <!-- UTF-8 bundles are not supported by Java, so they must be converted during build -->
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>native2ascii-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-beta-1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>native2ascii</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
        <configuration>
          <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
          <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
                                    <version>4.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>6.0</version>
                                </artifactItem>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                                    <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
                                </artifactItem>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                                    <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
                                </artifactItem>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                                    <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
                                </artifactItem>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                                    <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-dev-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Indeed most likely this is about different ClassLoaders, hence could you please explain how you package custom plugin? if Maven based - provide pom.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare dependency on `org.sonarsource.java:sonar-java-plugin` and its components as `provided`. This is shown in [examples of custom rules](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-rules-examples/blob/d87a6b1ac0470ba740a77e63cceaa9ccf8b200f5/java-custom-rules/pom.xml#L34). Otherwise they will be packaged into your plugin and that's why same classes are loaded by different ClassLoaders.